# Only last radio button value bound to the model - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the plunkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/4nPZ63KoBIwtIviP6RAA?p=preview

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <label>
          <input type="radio" dafuqisdis ng-model="color.name" name="test" value="blue">
            Red
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" dafuqisdis ng-model="color.name" name="test" value="red">
            Blue
      </label>
      {{myForm['test'].$modelValue}}
</form>
```

Please check the model values and console values.
Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Your plunker is working fine. Whats the issue?

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: updated plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/WobaHSKkeJ80k5tEMhAh?p=preview ; replaced `console.log(form['test'].$modelValue);` to `console.log(scope.color.name);`